# What does upgrading Amphitheatre do? (and what caused it?)

Tags: kittens-game

I have an upgrade `^` symbol on Aqueduct and Amphitheatre. I know the Aqueduct upgrade will give me [Hydro Plant](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Buildings#Hydro_Plant) and came from Robotics, but what about the Amphitheater? It's not mentioned in the wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tried it: it turns into a Broadcast Tower that works like Amphitheatre but more effective. [This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/kittensgame/comments/3flcj6/broadcast_towers/) has some info.

The popup window says Culture 5/sec, Unhappiness reduction -75%, Max Culture 525.

As opposed to [Amphitheatre](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Amphitheatre&redirect=no) 0.005/tick (=?), Unhappiness reduction -4.8%, Maximum Culture +50

Comment: The max culture on Broadcast Tower can also vary upwards, depending on your excess power generation.